# Apache .htaccess Redirect and RedirectPermanent directives do nothing

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, 301-redirect

I am trying to do a very simple redirect for an entire web site using instructions from sites like [this](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/hosting/301-redirect/) and [this](https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/search-engine-optimization/how-to-implement-a-301-redirect-in-apache-htaccess-files/), and several others that say the same thing. I am using Apache. My .htaccess file contains this:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/
```

It does not have any effect at all. I've also tried using `RedirectPermanent`, with the same result. Is there another setting somewhere else that affects this?

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed another setting that controls redirects. To make Apache look at .htaccess, it is necessary to change the **AllowOverrides** line in the apache .conf file for the site:

```
<Directory /var/www/oldsite/>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride **None**
      Require all granted
</Directory>
```

You can replace **None** by **All** to enable all directives, or by **Fileinfo** if you simply want to enable the group of directives that include **Redirect**. You can read more about the **AllowOverride** control in the [Apache core guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

Comment: Another factor can be the depth that is configured to search Apache recursively, looking for `.htaccess` files that modify it's settings. If it only looks 2 levels directories deep and your `.htaccess` file is 3 levels deep, it won't work. Because you are causing Apache to have to look through every directory, up to the configured limit deep, it is bad for performance. Don't get me wrong, I still use them sometimes, but not if I can easily avoid it.